# How to handle TX error on dapp frontend?

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, astar

Testing contract on polkadotjs, we can easily see user defined or error given by runtime like this:

[image]

But working with same contract in frontend I am not able to handle error response in frontend. Anybody please share some ideas and any link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope the following sites will help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74051628/how-to-get-unique-smart-contract-errors-in-a-frontend-app-using-polkadot-js/75514368#75514368

https://medium.com/@realtakahashi-work/collection-of-samples-for-using-polkadot-js-with-astar-network-7c1b40fefe50